# How do I shoot a sphere to the cursor position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a small game in 3D space, with a top down view. I'm trying to have the player shoot when left clicking, and I want the bullet (a sphere) to go in the direction of the cursor. The problem is that it is not catching the mouse position correctly, it always returns 0 on the x and z axis. (I hardcoded the y axis so the bullet doesn't fly into the camera).
This means no matter where the cursor is or where the player is on the screen, the bullets shoot in the direction of 0,0 on x and z. I am instantiating the bullets from a PlayerController() script.

My code:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5.0f;
    private Vector3 bulletTarget;
    private Vector3 bulletDirection;

    void Start()
    {
        //set projectile target on start
        bulletTarget = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        bulletTarget.y = 0.5f;

        //set direction
        bulletDirection = (bulletTarget - new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y ,transform.position.z)).normalized;

        Debug.Log("Target: " + bulletTarget + ", Direction: " + bulletDirection);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(bulletDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

How can I fix it so that the bullet shoots in the direction of my cursor instead of to the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ScreenToWorldPoint**

The vector3 parameter of `ScreenToWorldPoint` needs to have the z component set.  The z component is the distance from the camera into the world.  If the camera is not tilted, you can calculate the distance as follows.

```
var screenDepth = camera.transform.position.y - camera.nearClipPlane - objectPosition.y;
```

If the camera is tilted, you will have to compensate for the angle to determine how far from the camera the world point should be.  Setting the y component on the result after the fact will not produce precise results.

**ScreenPointToRay**

Another solution is to create a plane in the scene at the height you want the bullet to travel.  Put that plane on a layer that you can raycast against.

```
var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 1000, LayerMask.GetMask("BulletPlane"))
{
    bulletTarget = hit.point;
}
```

You can set the collider to `isTrigger` so it will not interfere with scene objects, or adjust the collision matrix.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly how I wanted