# ScreenToWorldPoint in Unity doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm quite new in code, and i'm trying to do my first game, however i'm encountering a problem :
The ScreenToWorldPoint doesn't work anymore :

I did a script for my 2d game in which I wanted that the gun of my character follows the direction of the player's mouse, so tbh I've asked ChatGPT to see how to do that and saw that with ScreenToWorldPoint and Input.mousePosition I could do that and it worked !

However since 2 days the script doesn't work anymore, the fun only follow the center of the screen/camera, I made a lot of changes in my game and I don't really know what made the script broke.

BTW i saw (yet didn't really understand why) that it could have been an issue with ScreenToWorldPoint z axis and that u had to set it at 10 (why 10 i don't understand and english not being my mothertongue doesn't help I guess), i've tested each and every possibility but neither 10 nor 9 nor 1000 and so on worked

Here's my script, I hope that someone will find a solution /

````
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Netcode;


public class GunController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Transform characterTransform;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject projectilePrefab;
    public float reloadTime = 0.5f;
    private bool canShoot = true;
    private List<GameObject> projectiles = new List<GameObject>();
    public Transform gunTransform;
    public float testDebugCam = 1001;

    void Start()
    {
        characterTransform = transform.parent;
    }

    

    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePosition.z = testDebugCam;
        Vector2 direction = mousePosition - transform.position;
        float angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.right, direction);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);

        if (canShoot && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 gunOffset = new Vector3(1.2f, 0f, 0f); // Adjust the offset based on your gun's position
            Vector3 spawnPosition = transform.position + transform.rotation * gunOffset;
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle);

            GameObject newProjectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
            ProjectileController projectileController = newProjectile.GetComponent<ProjectileController>();
            if (projectileController != null)
            {
                projectileController.damage = 10;
            }
            projectiles.Add(newProjectile);

            StartCoroutine(Shoot());
            StartCoroutine(Destroyproj(newProjectile));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Shoot()
    {
        canShoot = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
        canShoot = true;
    }

    IEnumerator Destroyproj(GameObject projectile)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f); // Destroy after x seconds
        if (projectiles.Contains(projectile))
        {
            projectiles.Remove(projectile);
            Destroy(projectile);
        }
    }
}```

BTW i'm suggesting that the bug occured because the player is only spawned after a bit of time, (when the player host or join a game) and the bug appeared when I implemented the online function so maybe it has to do something with this.
````

Comment: The problem is that `ScreenToWorldPoint` takes a Vector3, with the z component being the distance from the camera.  Implicitly converting from Vector2 to Vector3 gives a z of 0, which means the world point will be 0 units from the camera.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76177010/how-do-i-shoot-a-sphere-to-the-cursor-position/76177942#76177942) on how to calculate the distance, with an alternative method using ScreenPointToRay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! SO after tested your solution, tbh my problem was not solved but I've found the solution, the script didn't work because my camera projection was set to perspective and not orthographic. That's why it worked before, and I think it started when i've reseted my cam and that unity made it a perspective.